# Sum inventory item groups

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to sum all starting inventories and cap inventory amounts of product groups.  Initial output will give starting inventories and caps of specific products, but I'd like to roll up the total starting inventory into the product group level.

This is in Oracle SQL.  I've tried removing the product category and adding the SUM() function to the starting inventory, but it still is not rolling up the sum to the group level.  There is a SELECT statement in the FROM clause... maybe there is an issue there???

```
SELECT OPRVIEW_OBSERVATION_DATE,
       OPRVIEW.LOOKUP_CODE                                                      OPRVIEW_LOOKUP_CODE,
       HSALE001V.GROUPBUD                                                       HSALE001V_GROUPBUD,
       sum(HSALE001V.CAP)                                                           HSALE001V_CAP,
       sum(OPRVIEW.START_INV)                                                        OPRVIEW_START_INV
FROM   (SELECT h.observation_date,
               loc.lookup_code,
               inv.start_inv,
               inv.product
        FROM   apps.nlas_inventory inv,
               apps.nlas_header h,
               apps.nlas_location loc
        WHERE  inv.header_id = h.id
               AND loc.id = h.location_id) OPRVIEW
       INNER JOIN (select rtrim(ltrim(gnmcu))   as siteBUD,
                          rtrim(ltrim(GNALPH1)) as itemBUD,
                          GNDC                  as StatusBUD,
                          GNAN25                as CAP,
                          GNALPH2               as GroupBUD
                   from   hsale001) HSALE001V
         ON OPRVIEW.LOOKUP_CODE = HSALE001V.SITEBUD
            AND OPRVIEW.PRODUCT = HSALE001V.ITEMBUD
WHERE  ( ( ( OPRVIEW.OBSERVATION_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('2019-08-07 00 00 00', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE('2019-08-07 23 59 59', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss') )
           AND ( OPRVIEW.LOOKUP_CODE IN ( '123' ) ) )
         AND ( HSALE001V.STATUSBUD IN ( 'CA' ) ) )
GROUP  BY FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(OPRVIEW.OBSERVATION_DATE, 'yyyyddd'))) - 1900000,
          OPRVIEW.LOOKUP_CODE,
          HSALE001V.GROUPBUD,
          HSALE001V.CAP,
          OPRVIEW.START_INV
```

Current output (lists out each product per line... product is not displayed):

```
DATE    SITE    GROUP           CAP     INVENTORY
119219  123         2             0          3778
119219  123         2         24000         23165
```

Desired output:

```
DATE    SITE    GROUP           CAP     INVENTORY
119219  123         2             0         26943
```

Comment: So the reason you're getting that output is based on how you're grouping your columns to derive a sum.  if you remove cap from your group by statement you should return a single row.  however I think your cap will return 24000 instead of 0 which is your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As also mentioned in the comment, there is problem with `group by`. But there are last 2 columns which do not require in `group by`.

```
SELECT OPRVIEW_OBSERVATION_DATE,
       OPRVIEW.LOOKUP_CODE                                                      OPRVIEW_LOOKUP_CODE,
       HSALE001V.GROUPBUD                                                       HSALE001V_GROUPBUD,
       sum(HSALE001V.CAP)                                                           HSALE001V_CAP,
       sum(OPRVIEW.START_INV)                                                        OPRVIEW_START_INV
FROM   (SELECT h.observation_date,
               loc.lookup_code,
               inv.start_inv,
               inv.product
        FROM   apps.nlas_inventory inv,
               apps.nlas_header h,
               apps.nlas_location loc
        WHERE  inv.header_id = h.id
               AND loc.id = h.location_id) OPRVIEW
       INNER JOIN (select rtrim(ltrim(gnmcu))   as siteBUD,
                          rtrim(ltrim(GNALPH1)) as itemBUD,
                          GNDC                  as StatusBUD,
                          GNAN25                as CAP,
                          GNALPH2               as GroupBUD
                   from   hsale001) HSALE001V
         ON OPRVIEW.LOOKUP_CODE = HSALE001V.SITEBUD
            AND OPRVIEW.PRODUCT = HSALE001V.ITEMBUD
WHERE  ( ( ( OPRVIEW.OBSERVATION_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('2019-08-07 00 00 00', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE('2019-08-07 23 59 59', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss') )
           AND ( OPRVIEW.LOOKUP_CODE IN ( '123' ) ) )
         AND ( HSALE001V.STATUSBUD IN ( 'CA' ) ) )
GROUP  BY FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(OPRVIEW.OBSERVATION_DATE, 'yyyyddd'))) - 1900000,
          OPRVIEW.LOOKUP_CODE,
          HSALE001V.GROUPBUD;
          --HSALE001V.CAP, -- not required
          --OPRVIEW.START_INV -- not required
```

You need only columns in the `group by` using which you need your result to be grouped as also its name suggests.

`Aggregate functions` are mostly used on non grouped columns.

**Note**: `CAP` will be 24000 using this query.

Cheers!!

Comment: Wow!  What a silly mistake on my part.  I completely missed that I added my aggregate functions to the GROUP BY.  I guess that's what happens when you stare at the same snippet of SQL for too long!!  Thanks all!